# Clean Architecture in NET Framework 4.5 / 4.7.2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, clean-architecture, onion-architecture, .net-4.7.2

Is it possible to work with clean architecture in ASP.NET MVC 5 on the .NET Framework 4.5 and 4.7.2? I ask the question because I see more examples on .NET Core.

Thanks

I prefer known work clean architecture for .NET framework 4.7.2 for an ASP.NET MVC 5 project written in C#.

Comment: Well, since .NET Core is the current, new technology - obviously you'll see more (new) posts about clean architecture in .NET Core. But it's *just* an architecture principle - it's not bound to any particular language or runtime stack.

Comment: Voting to close this. It's obvious architecture is often not bound to specific language or tech stack. Asking a question "is it possible ..." that should get an answer "yes it is" doesn't bring much value. Try to reformulate the question so that specific issue is presented and a specific, technical answer can be provided.

Comment: @Vajra this might help you impliment [Clean-Architecture in MVC 5 project](https://matthewrenze.com/articles/clean-architecture-in-asp-net-mvc-5/)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is still possible to do clean architecture. I still maintain it in my office

[my project solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IXAL.png)

[project properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2wlC.jpg)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).